# Remove pagingation_base for specific taxonomy types

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, pagination

I want to remove the default pagination_base 'page' from the pagination URL for two taxonomy terms only. I don't want to remove the pagination base globally (like $wp_rewrite->pagination_base = '';).

I've used the below htaccess rules for testing purpose:

```
RewriteRule ^bransch/ljudisolering/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /bransch/ljudisolering/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^bransch/ljudisolering/([0-9]+)/?$ /?index.php?bygg_branch=ljudisolering&paged=$1 [L]
```

When I test this htaccess rule checker like https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ with URL http://site.local/bransch/ljudisolering/page/2, it shows the correct output.

But this doesn't change anything in WordPress site. Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "But this doesn't change anything in WordPress site" - what URL(s) is your site requesting?

Comment: @MrWhite I want to remove page/ in the pagination URLs  for branch taxonomy type- http://site.local/bransch/ljudisolering/page/2. Means I want http://site.local/bransch/ljudisolering/2 instead of http://site.local/bransch/ljudisolering/page/2

Comment: Ok, but that isn't something you should be doing in `.htaccess` (indeed, this won't change anything in the WordPress site - it's not how `.htaccess` works). You need to change this is WordPress itself and make sure that WP generates the appropriate URLs.